# Invalidate nested .eslintrc

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've a node project which works with ES6 and serves an angular project in public folder:

```
├── public
│   ├── client.js
│   └── .eslintrc
├── server.js
└── .eslintrc
```

I would like to use `airbnb` extension in server and `angular` extension in client side so I've tried:

**.eslintrc**:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

**public/.eslintrc**:

```
{
    "extends": "angular"
}
```

The result is that in `client.js` rules for `airbnb` are being applied too. Is it possible to invalidate parent `.eslintrc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `root: true` to the top of any config to stop ESLint from searching parent folders for config files. So you should update your `public/.eslintrc` and add top level property `"root": true`.